# Passing JSON as parameter to a Javascript method

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript. I am writing a Java code which internally write code to call predefined Javascript method.

I have a Javascript method defined as:

```
  function myfunction(url, params) {
        $.post(url, params);
  }
```

This send params which is a JSON to the URL as post (I suppose).

My Java code generate HTML on the fly which internally generate something like:

```
<iframe onLoad="myfunction(myinternal, {"system":"abcdef", "token": "12345"})"> ......
```

However, this fails to run. Page inspection gave me:

```
SyntaxError: invalid property id
       myfunction(myinternal, {
                               ^
```

What did I do wrong here?

Many thanks

Comment: You are ending the attribute with your second `"`. Either wrap the attribute in `'` or use javascript to capture the onload event.

Comment: Also note that what you are calling "a JSON" is in fact a Javascript object literal.

Answer (score 8):

Your HTML has syntax errors. Should be more like this:

```
<iframe onLoad="myfunction(myinternal, {\"system\":\"abcdef\", \"token\": \"12345\"})">
```

or wrap in a single quote:

```
<iframe onLoad='myfunction(myinternal, {"system":"abcdef", "token": "12345"})'>
```

**EDIT: (per first comment)**

```
<iframe onLoad="myfunction(myinternal, {&quot;system&quot;:&quot;abcdef&quot;, &quot;token&quot;: &quot;12345&quot;})">
```

Comment: The first solution is not correct, html does not allow escaping like that. You should use `&quot;` in that case.

Comment: Thanks @RenéWolferink, I will edit the solution to eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2yfce773%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) your quotes inside the json object.

Answer (score 1):

You used double quotes `"` in your JSON. They are interpreted by the HTML parser as the end of the `onLoad` attribute.

Try with single quotes, like this :

```
<iframe onLoad="myfunction(myinternal, {'system':'abcdef', 'token': '12345'})">
```